# How to prevent any kind of software from automatic check for updates?

Tags: software-updates

I wanted to disable all automatic software updates so I went to gnome app Software > Update Preferences and Disabled the Automatic Updates toggle. However I still get update prompts for flatpaks. Is there a way to disable all auto updates?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Distribution you are running, you can check if it implemented an Automated Updating Service for flatpaks like described here (https://www.jwillikers.com/automate-flatpak-updates-with-systemd) by using

```sh
ls /etc/systemd/system/* | grep flatpak
```

and then running if you find one that is called flatpak upgrades.

```sh
systemctl disable [service-name]
```

If you're on a debian based distribution, you can also check if the package "unattended-upgrades" is installed (With Ubuntu this comes preinstalled) and remove it:

```sh
dpkg -l | grep 'unattended-upgrades' # Find out if unattended-upgrades is installed
apt remove unattended-upgrades # Remove Package.
```